# Insert millions of rows into a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I have 2 tables one is record and other is codes table. I would like to insert millions of codes into the codes table. It has a foreign key reference to the record key. Before inserting to the codes table we need to check if the codes already exist or not.

Example: Codes starting number = 50 and quantity = 5.

So it will generate 50,51,52,53,54 values in the codes table and ids which will refer to the record table.

In actual I am inserting millions of codes. Right now I have used a while loop which makes the whole process slow. Will batch be of any use. If so please let me know how.

My SQL query is:

/

*

```
--EXEC  [SaveCodesAndPrintedEncodingByQuantity] @code ='2000000' , @quantity =100000, @recordType ='DocumentRecord',@codeType='MAGID'  
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveCodesAndPrintedEncodingByQuantity] (
    @code VARCHAR(max)
    ,@codeLength INT = 9
    ,@quantity INT
    ,@recordType VARCHAR(max)
    ,@codeType VARCHAR(max)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OutputId AS TABLE (Id INT)
    DECLARE @codeInt INT;
    DECLARE @output VARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @sum INT = 0
    DECLARE @codeValue INT
    DECLARE @OutParam VARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @RecordId INT
    DECLARE @BatchSize INT;
    SET @codeInt = CONVERT(BIGINT, @code)
    SET @sum = @codeInt + @quantity
    
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    
    BEGIN TRY
        WHILE (@codeInt < @sum)
        BEGIN
            SET @codeValue = @codeInt
            EXEC [dbo].[GetPrintedEncoding] @code = @codeInt
                ,@OutParam = @output OUTPUT
            IF NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM codes
                    WHERE code =  @codeInt
                    )
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO RECORDS (
                    RecordType
                    ,DateCreated
                    )
                OUTPUT inserted.Id
                INTO @OutputId(Id)
                VALUES (
                    @recordType
                    ,GETDATE()
                    )
                SELECT @RecordId = Id
                FROM @OutputId
                INSERT INTO CODES (
                    CODE
                    ,RecordID
                    ,CodeType
                    ,PrintedEncoding
                    )
                VALUES (
                     @codeValue             
                    ,@RecordId
                    ,@codeType
                    ,@output
                    )
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR (
                        'Code already exists'
                        ,16
                        ,1
                        )
                     
            END
            SET @codeInt = @codeInt + 1
        END
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
    
        ROLLBACK
    END CATCH
END
```

- 

Comment: where is your while loop of code? could you show us thanks

Comment: doing your queries in batches of 5000 rows is a good rule of thumb for performance. It's the threshold for lock escalation.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis - I dont know batch inert..I saw few examples of batch update though

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I know `UPDATE` & `DELETE` more than 5000 might meet the lock escalation in sql-server, but I am not sure `INSERT INTO` will be. could you share the link about `INSERT`  lock escalation thanks

Comment: Ultimately you don't need to loop; you should be working in a set-based fashion and if necessary, modify the *GetPrintedEncoding* procedure to work with a tabletype / temp table and just insert all rows in a single batch.

Comment: @stu - could give me an example please.

Comment: It is not clear where those values are coming from, ie: @CodeType and the need to that procedure. Likely this could be done using some gaps and islands query, plus Insert into select ... EXISTS in a single shot?

Comment: @cetin basoz - updated. The codetype all comes from web

Comment: Your edit doesn't explain what you are trying to do. It doesn't give a clue why you ever need that GetPrintedEncoding executed in an loop. As I said before, I think you don't need it in the first place and likely should end up 1-2 inserts.